# Is it possible to pass through a Vue component via Mustache syntax {{}}?

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js

I have a markdown file with YAML frontmatter. In the frontmatter, I want to refer to a component such as:

```
---
title: Hello world
component: <component-a></component-a>
---
Lorem ipsum...
```

I want to refer to this in the vue file via {{page.component}}. Is there a way to have vue recognize this? Right now, it just spits out , instead of the actual component. If it helps, I am using Nuxt.

Answer (score 1):

Try to use [`component`](https://v3.vuejs.org/api/built-in-components.html#component) to render it like :

```
 <component :is="page.component" />
```